# how to write sql query for max consecutive ids that have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this.

```
ID    someoneBoolean    
-------------------   
1        true
2        true
3        false
4        false
5        true
6        true
7        true
8        false
9        false
10       false
```

How to write sql queries for EX1 and Ex2?

EX1: find the max numbers of consecutive ids that have value true.

Output: 3

EX2: find the max numbers of consecutive ids between 6~10 that have value true.

Output: 2

**Edited:**
How to return the ids instead of returning the max number.
So ex1 would return 5,6,7
and EX2: 6,7

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Hint: Use user-defined variables to hold the previous row's value, the running count of same values, and the starting ID of the current run. Reset the variables whenever the value changes.

Comment: (To be fair, a lot of the time it's indistinguishable from a free coding service)